# PHP Base64 Decode to PDF browser output

Tags: php, file, pdf, base64

I'm working with a web service that returns PDF documents as file streams (base64_encoded.)

Here is what I have so far:

```
$data     = $response->data;
$data_decoded = base64_decode($data);

$file = fopen($file_name,'wb+');
fwrite($file, $data_decoded);
fclose($file);

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename='.urlencode($file_name).'');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
```

Still the darn thing will not output a valid file.

I've ran the string through an online base64 decoder and the file is created!

Any thoughts/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does @readfile accept a file pointer as an argument?  I thought you had to pass it a string filename.

Comment: I agree with @Deadron comment. Also since you are emitting the whole file, there is no role for 'Accept-Ranges' header. If you have no need for the file once this script ends, you could skip writing it to a file and just echo($data_decoded) instead of using readfile(). Of course, for the content length you'd use strlen($data_decoded) instead of filesize().

Comment: Let's try: file_put_contents($file_name, $data_decoded);

Comment: Does it still fail with @readfile($file_name); ? Though, why do you read the file again if you already have it in memory in the $data_decoded variable?
Just echoing that variable should be enough and saves you one filesystem access.